# Initialize array to my class c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I,m this class :

```
class Foo {
private:
    Objet grid;
    static Player *players[2];
public:
    Foo(int len, string ps1, string ps2);
};
```

When i do this :

```
Foo::Foo(int len, string ps1, string ps2){
    grid.setLen(len);
    players[0] = new Ange(ps1, grid.getLen()/2, grid.getLen/2);
    players[1] = new Demon(ps2);
}
```

`Player` is a `class` `abstract` and `Ange` et `Demon` herited to `class` `Player`

I'm this error to xCodes when i compile

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "Partie::joueurs", referenced from:
>   Partie::Partie(int, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >) in Partie.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

help me please !!!

Excuse my english i'm french

Comment: Why are you initializing a static member in a constructor?

Comment: You have an undefined virtual method. Which is required for class construction. All virtual methods (not pure) must be defined somewhere.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Where exactly do you see a virtual member in that code?

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with that code. Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Hoo I'm sorry I do not know why I'm gonna put that same static I deleted it and there it Works

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That is my wild guess, as I don't speak French... But it is likely you are right and I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static member variable is only *declared*, you need to *define* it as well.

It's simplest done by adding, in a source file somewhere:

```
Player *Foo::players[2];
```

Though you should not initialize static member variables in the constructor, what do you think would happen if you create *Two* (or more) `Foo` objects?